# <nav> resizing to fit child contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried every CSS trick in the book today to get my parent nav tag `home-main-nav-menu` to resize according to it's children and grand children, but I can't for the life of me get it to work. If someone can provide and explanation of how the fix this that would be much terrific, and an explanation of why elements don't naturally expanded to fit it's child contents would be even better. Thanks! [see image and css for reference]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main-ul').children('li').on('click', function() {
     $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

```css
.home-main-nav-menu{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: cyan;
}
.A{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: purple;
}
.B{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -40.5px;
}
.A > ul {
  display: none;
}
.main-ul{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: green;
  width: 95.5%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
ul{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class = "home-main-nav-menu">
    <ul class = "main-ul">
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">a</a></li>
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">b</a>
        <ul>
          <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">c</a></li>
          <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">d</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">e</a></li>
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">f</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">f</a></li>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">g</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">h</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">i</a></li>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">j</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">k</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">l</a></li>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">m</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[see CSS for color map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okcUn.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your class:

```
ul{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Is positioning all the the `ul` as `absolute` and pulling all those elements out of the normal flow of the document and into its own layer. This effectively disconnects the `nav` from its child `ul`s even though the HTML structure shows them as a group.

Changing it to:

```
ul{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

Solves the issue. This still pulls the `ul` elements out of the flow, but without specifying a specific position, keeps the element where it is in the flow and holds the original position within the main flow of the document.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)**:

> **absolute**
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow; ***no
>   space is created for the element in the page layout***. Instead, it is
>   positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any;
>   otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its
>   final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and
>   left. This value creates a new stacking context when the value of
>   z-index is not auto. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, and
>   they do not collapse with any other margins.
>
> **relative**
>
> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the
>   document, and then offset relative to itself based on the values of
>   top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position
>   of any other elements; ***thus, the space given for the element in the
>   page layout is the same as if position were static.*** This value creates
>   a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto. The
>   effect of relative on table-*-group, table-row, table-column,
>   table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

Also, removing:

```
width: 95.5%;
```

from the `.main-ul` class keeps the `ul` elements from overflowing the parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main-ul').children('li').on('click', function() {
     $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

```css
.home-main-nav-menu{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: cyan;
}
.A{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: purple;
}

.B{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -40.5px;
}
.A > ul {
  display: none;
}
.main-ul{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: green;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

ul{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class = "home-main-nav-menu">
    <ul class = "main-ul">
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">a</a></li>
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">b</a>
        <ul>
          <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">c</a></li>
          <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">d</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">e</a></li>
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">f</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">f</a></li>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">g</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">h</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">i</a></li>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">j</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      <li class = "A"><a href = "#/">k</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">l</a></li>
        <li class = "B"><a href = "#/">m</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however, it then creates the dropdown elements to drop very odd. I think this is how I had my code yesterday, but I am not certain.Why does absolute "pull elements out of there natural flow?"

Comment: ahhhhh I had position relative in a the wrong class. I see what you are saying now.

Comment: I know this is getting picky, but that one moves everything in sync like I want it to, but what if I wanted to keep the divs below it in the same place instead of pushing down with the content? would Z index work? and that moves my wholeeeee main element list :O

Comment: @DexterFreelander Then you'd put `postion:absolute` on the `nav` parent container, not the `ul` child elements.

Comment: I'm sorry I ment my "section and article" they are directly below the main nav bar. Your code creates issues (which I changed yesterday only to have this issue) the nav bar when expanded moves main nav bar li's to depth of children ul or li's however you want to look at it, and secondly, all content under the parent (home-main-nav-menu) are pushed down the page.

Comment: @DexterFreelander See my last comment above.

Comment: I have not parent container on nav. I only have the header and then nav would contains all menu bar stuff. :O why would I need a container around nav?

Comment: @DexterFreelander I didn't mean create a new container, I mean the container of the `ul` elements, which is your existing `nav`. My answer does answer your question, so please up vote it and mark it as the answer. If you have other questions beyond this, please post a new question.